# Linear functions of matrix exponential

Tags: algorithms, optimization

Given a matrix $A$ and a vector $v$, I'm aware there are efficient algorithms for computing $e^Av$, where efficient means significantly faster than computing $e^A$ and multiplying by $v$. For a diagonal matrix $D$, is there a similarly efficient algorithm to compute $$ e^A \cdot D = \sum_i (e^A)_{ii} D_{ii}?$$
In particular, is there an efficient way to compute the trace of the exponential?